# Jenkins workflow - tests/validation/build before push to remote

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, workflow, bitbucket

## Jenkins CI - bitbucket and git

I have seen a few workflows as I was reading about Jenkins and looking through some tutorials, but they tend to use hooks to pull from a repo then do the build. I would rather keep the master branch of my repo clean, and push feature branches to Jenkins when ready to merge. Jenkins would then run the format validation, tests and if it all goes well merge the branch with origin master.

Is this a common workflow? Is this even possible with Jenkins?

Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

`git clone --branch <branch_name> --single-branch <repo_url>` fetches a specific branch.

Do the building and testing and if successfull do the merge (or rebase)